# 23505: could not create unique index "IX_TechneDestinationSectionTitles_NormalizedName" DETAIL: Key ("NormalizedName")=() is duplicated

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi, clean-architecture, entity-framework-core-migrations

Fields of my Entity are Id, Title, NormalizedName & An enum.[class file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di0C3.jpg) After edit in configuration,[configurartion file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlgGs.jpg) I added Migration. After that I tried to update db. Then I got this Error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjkfk.jpg)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error indicates you you have at least 2 rows that have the same value in column NormalizedName. You cannot create a unique index on that column as long at that exists. Run `select NormalizedName, count(*) from Entity group by NormalizedName having count(*) > 1;` to find the duplicate values, correct that, and attempt creating the index again.  Alternatively, perhaps you need create a non-unique index.